# INSERT and SELECT arrays from Postgresql tables using Qt

Tags: postgresql, qt

I'm going to write a client application for `POSTGRESQL` using `Qt`. Is it possible to read arrays and write to arrays  using `QSqlQuery`? If yes, then I ask a small example. In google unequivocal answer to this question is not found.